# Building custom letters with openGL

Tags: c, opengl

I am currently working on a school project in openGL and I am re-creating [this](http://www.newbelgium.com/Images/Shiftcircle.jpg) and also plan on animating the gears and chain. Currently I am working on the letters / font. I have every letter build with `GL_POLYGON` except for the `S`, `P`, `G`, and `R`. These all present a challenge because they have curved edges. I have been brainstorming about how to best handle this but have yet to come up with anything.

What would be the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Any curve can be approximated by a series of lines.

Comment: So would it really just be the best option to take the tedious route and plot each point for those letters?

Comment: Or generate (render to) a texture at that resolution, and continuously draw that, but it might indeed be the easiest to implement a simple rasterizer.

Comment: There is one other consideration. Does GL_POLYGON work for concave polygons?